# how to delete tag pair without content inside it in VIM

Tags: vim

Assume I have this block:

```
<div>
<|p>
   <b>text</b>
</p>
</div>
```

So how to delete the p tag pair without the content inside it so It would become:

```
<div>
   <b>text</b>
</div>
```

Comment: is that pipe character supposed to be there?  `<|p>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: Place the cursor in line `<b>text</b>` then run the command `.-d|.+d`

Comment: | means the cursor position

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with Tim Pope's [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin.

```
dst
```

With plain Vim you can do:

```
yitcat<c-r>0
```

For more help see:

```
:h it
:h at
:h i_CTRL-R
:h "0
```

Comment: hey, how about remove the newline too, using dst don't remove the newline like this: `<div>nl<b>text</b>nl</div>`

Comment: Sorry, I do not know of a good way to do that. I know that [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) provides some different text objects variants which may work better.

Answer (score 1):

I have `othree/xml.vim` plugin installed. Move your cursor on the element you want to delete,  then `Leader + d` will do what you want, `leader + D` will remove the tag with content. There are some more features, you can check the doc.